# Wordpress adding mod_rewrite not working

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite

I am trying to add a rewrite rule to wordpress. For starters, i want a rewrite rule which would get rid of all text after testpage/, so that if i go to localhost/testpage/bla/bla/bla i will be redirected to localhost/testpage

It doesn't sound very usefull, but i am sure that if i get this working i also get the rest working. However, this simple thing is not working, and i have no idea why. I have a plugin which shows all the rewrite rules and which has an option to flush them, and the rewriterule is added. However, if i try to go to localhost/testpage/bla/bla/bla i get the message page not found. This is my code:

```
static function add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) 
{
        $new_rules = array(
        'testpage/(.*)' => 'testpage/'
        );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}


add_action('generate_rewrite_rules','add_rewrite_rules');
```

Comment: Have you flushed the rewrite rules (say by going to the permalinks page in the admin console)?

Comment: yes              (comments must be at least 15 characters in length..)